# Busch Bavarian Beer can

Tags: history, cans

I cannot find any information on this can. I believe it is from the 1950s.

[image: BUSCH BAVARIAN BEER]

[Busch Bavarian Beer](https://www.pinterest.ca/abinbev/busch-bavarian-beer/)

The words BUSCH BAVARIAN BEER is on the front and back. It is printed over mountains with 2 black circles around it. The outer circle is a little bigger then the inter circle. Below the word beer is product of U.S.A. Inside the circle at the bottom it says clear and bright as mountain air. Below the circle it say Contents 12 FL. OZ. On top is a Kansas tax stamp. Inside a black circle are the words Busch Bavarian beer. Then also inside is another small circle with a sunflower. In the middle of the flower is a 12. Going around the large circle on the  end it says Kansas C.M.B.Tax paid 94/100 cent. At the front very bottom of the can it says Brewed and canned at ST. Louis, MO. By Anheuser Busch, INC.    2nd. Beer can is a Stroh Light. 12oz. A common can except this has a Founding Sponsor Liberty 1886-1986 printed on the side of the can with the liberties head in the middle of a little square.  Thank You

Comment: I found this thread that has some information. https://www.beeradvocate.com/community/threads/pabst-claims-millercoors-is-trying-to-put-it-out-of-business.594304/page-4#post-6291449

Answer (score 1):

And, according to [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anheuser-Busch_brands#Busch) and [its source (ref. [26])](https://web.archive.org/web/20100407083621/http://www.beercollections.com/Breweries/Missouri/Busch_Beer.htm), you may be right:

> [**Busch Bavarian Beer**](https://www.google.com/search?q=busch+bavarian+beer) was introduced in 1955 on national TV. Busch Beer was originally sold in the South, Midwest, and Mid-Alantic regions of the U.S.